# How to represent geo spatial circular or Polygon area in spring data neo4j spatial?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-spatial

I need to represent an circular or polygon area of a place in map. Any place is not  a single lon lan piont in map. It is a polygon area. Currently what i have is single single indexed wkt field with single point lon lat representation. How to represent circular or polygon region information in neo4j?

Answer (score 3):

You should also be able to use the polygon representation in the WKT field, not sure it works but it should. As it will index the bounding box of the polygon.

With SDN 3.1.M1 there is also more support for geo-types like polygon, circle and box which make it a bit easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using REST of how to use polygons in Neo4j Spatial.

First, set up a spatial index that is configured to use WKT geometries.

```
POST http://localhost:7474﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿/db/data/index/node {"name":"tickle","config":{"provider":"spatial","wkt":"wkt"}}
```

The name of my index is "tickle". If you don't already have the base nodes for the RTree established, this call will do it. Among those nodes is a layer node. The layer is also named "tickle". If the base nodes for the RTree are already established, a new layer node will be added. The name of the property that will contain the WKT geometries in the nodes that I will add is "wkt".

Now, add a polygon node.

```
POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit {"statements" : [ {"statement" : "CREATE (n:City {name : 'Bartown', wkt : 'POLYGON ((-97.06138 32.837, -97.06133 32.836, -97.06124 32.833, -97.06127 32.832, -97.06138 32.837))"') RETURN id(n)" } ] }
```

This does nothing from the Neo4j Spatial viewpoint. It just adds a node that has a name property ("Bartown") and a wkt property containing a lon/lat polygon. Notice that the polygon is formed of pairs of longitudes and latitudes, each representing a vertex of the polygon. The last vertex must have the same coordinates as the first vertex (this makes it a closed figure). Note the node id that is returned. It is used in the next step.

Now add the node to the RTree. If the ID of the node you created is not 4, change the number at the end of the statement below to the value just returned.

```
POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/tickle {"value":"dummy","key":"dummy","uri":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/4"}
```

If you display a graph of the nodes, you will find that a node has been added to the RTree that has an "id" property that matches the internal ID of the original node (4), but an internal ID that is different.

So, now you have added a node to the RTree and the spatial index. If you want to add more, simply create more nodes and add them to the index.

If you do a query using REST, Neo4j Spatial will return RTree nodes, which must be dereferenced using the "id" property to get the original nodes. As an example,

```
POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/findGeometriesWithinDistance {"pointX":"-97.0", "pointY":"32.0", "distanceInKm":"1000.0", "layer":"tickle"}
```

will return the RTree node (5). On the other hand, if you do the query using Cypher, the original node is returned. (I'm not going to bother embedding the Cypher in REST this time.)

START n=node:tickle("withinDistance:[32.0, -97.0, 1000.0]") RETURN n;

Notice that the ordering of the coordinates in the Cypher call are latitude, longitude, max distance. This is reverse of everything else, and is a bug.

I hope this is enough to get you started if you haven't gotten it sorted out already. I just finished slogging through this myself!